# lldb C local variable not printing

Tags: c, lldb, llvm-clang

```
Value eval(Value arg, Table env) {
if (arg.tag == ConsCell) {
    Value operator = car(arg);
    Value operands = cdr(arg); // <- debugger stopped here
```

If I print the argument `arg` with `p arg`, I get:

```
(lldb) p arg
(Value) $0 = {
  data = {
    number = 1068272
    list = 0x0000000100104cf0
    symbol = 0x0000000100104cf0 "?L\x10"
  }
  tag = ConsCell
}
```

But if `p operator`, I get:

```
(lldb) p operator
error: expected a type
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

However, using `frame variable operator` works:

```
(lldb) frame variable operator
(Value) operator = {
  data = {
  number = 1068208
  list = 0x0000000100104cb0
  symbol = 0x0000000100104cb0 "\x10L\x10"
}
  tag = ConsCell
}
```

What's going wrong when I'm using `p operator`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lldb evaluates expression in hybrid of C++ and Objective-C.  `operator`, the name of your variable, is a reserved keyword in C++.  When you use the `p` command (which is an alias to `expression` command), lldb passes your expression to clang to parse and evaluate in C++/Objective-C (or, if you're debugging a Swift method, parse and evaluate in Swift).  Even though your program is written in straight C, your expressions are evaluated as C++ expressions and that's not a valid C++ expression.

`frame variable` (`fr v` for short) doesn't go through a compiler for evaluation, it tries to do simple parsing of the variable path provided.  It can do simple dereferencing and following of pointers, but it can't cast values for instance.